# Global Exception Handling in a Multi-Threaded Jungle - Fail Safe/Restart

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

**Situation :**
 I have a pretty complex Console App launching multiple threads, each one generating sub-threads and so on (for 3 or 4 levels). Everything is mainly delegate/events driven.
I know try/catch blocks in the scope where a thread is created are of no relevance to that thread when it starts executing. I want to find a clean way to manage this.

For illustration purpose, the following pattern appears often at many levels in my app :

```
    public void Activate()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Activate_Entrypoint);    
    }
```

**Issue :**
 
As long as I was still developing/debugging, Exceptions were thrown "on the flow" on a micro level.
However, I need to build and prepare a production package now, so everything needs to run smoothly in case of exception. So I need a clean user message/log and shutdown/restart at the top level.

**Exception Raising mode :**
 
I have implemented the OnUnhandledException

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(OnUnhandledException);
```

However it does NOT seem to be ever raised as I would expect.***Erratum Edit :*** it does raise properly indeed, It was not firing because I declared the binding too late in the main.
I have nested a division by zero in different threads that I enable/disable to monitor the app's behaivour.

**IMPORTANT - Clean Design :**
 
I need the Main Top Thread to be just a nutshell, having an observer on the rest of the App. 
If a critical error occurs, I would like this thread to **stop everything** (Aborting the child App thread it has launched), and then **Restart it Again**. You heard it : I don't want an ugly crash to just stop everything. I would like to isolate the App in a wrapper thread that would take care of checking that it is still running and relaunch it (It's a 24/7 server side App).
I would also like to avoid handling every possible exception everywhere this would be hell. I just want a safety belt to let unhandled exception blow if they happen to occur and manage them in a clean way by relaunching the Application from the Main Top Thread.

**Possible solutions :**
 
I came across a few posts about flag passing and regular checking among thread. This sounds interesting, though it can get complicated when using a lots of thread levels.
I am using Quartz.net to schedule a constant scan task on some flags and take action to make threads stop and restart if needed. Not finished yet, just giving it a shot.

*If I have missed something please bear with me and just ask for details, this is not a field I am really comfortable with (not yet).*

**Resources :** 
[Joseph Albahari on Threading/](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: You need to get AppDomain.UnhandledException working.  Very unclear why you would have trouble with it.

Comment: Regarding UnhandledException not being called, have you tried throwing an exception explicitly rather than dividing by zero?  I'm not entirely sure, but I believe division by zero will only result in an exception in a 'checked' context; by default, the compiler will use 'unchecked' arithmetic and will thus produce NaN or INF values rather than throwing exceptions.

Comment: Just to be sure: there is only 1 (one) AppDomain ever?

Comment: @DanBryant : Tired to throw an Exception. Same result.

Comment: OOOOPS : SOrry, the UnhandledException is raised. See edit.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you are facing is documented in [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx):

> Unhandled exceptions on thread pool threads terminate the process. There are three exceptions to this rule:
>
> A ThreadAbortException is thrown in a thread pool thread, because Abort was called.
>
> An AppDomainUnloadedException is thrown in a thread pool thread, because the application domain is being unloaded.
>
> The common language runtime or a host process terminates the thread.
>
> If any of these exceptions are unhandled in threads created by the common language runtime, the exception terminates the thread, but the common language runtime does not allow the exception to proceed further.
>
> If these exceptions are unhandled in the main thread, or in threads that entered the runtime from unmanaged code, they proceed normally, resulting in termination of the application.

Based on this information, you will have to handle the exceptions in each of the parent threads.

The way that we handle a very similar design is to keep track of each thread that is started in a collection within the parent.

On each pass through the parent process' main loop, we check the status of each thread.
When the thread is no longer active (or isn't responsive for a period of time), we know that something has gone haywire, so we perform a graceful shutdown of the child processes and then, for all but the top-level process, we terminate the thread.

Then, when the main thread performs its next pass through, it will see that the child threads have died and will restart them as necessary.

We have been running with this same basic design for at least 10 years (we started the core in VB6) and it has performed extremely well in a number of different configurations and loads.

Comment: Yes. That will raise ThreadAbortException and, if that is unhandled, .Net will just terminate the thread and not continue propagating the exception.

Comment: Hummm... Ok then. I'll give this a careful look. Thank you